# Spinnaker: not able to access with localhost:9000 on Azure WM

Tags: azure, spinnaker

I have deployed Spinnaker successfully on an Azure VM.  I am able to successfully connect via "ssh" and the outputs of `curl http://9000` and `curl http:8084/health` are appropriate.  Did the tunnelling as documented.

However from my host machine browser I am not able to open the Deck UI.  The `http://localhost:9000` from my Mac Chrome Browser says:

> "This site can’t be reached.  localhost refused to connect."

Comment: Have you opened port 9000 for external access (via endpoints / network security group)

Comment: Thanks David.  Yes, I have opened up the port 9000 in both inbound and outbound rules of the networks security group (for any source / destination).

Answer (score 0):

As long as your VM has a public IP/DNS the following instructions should work on a Mac, I just tried them against an instance of Spinnaker that I have running on an Azure VM in my subscription.

• On your local machine do the following:

• Add this to ~/.ssh/config (if file does not exist create it) and populate with content below.  Give the file execute permissions (chmod 700 ~/.ssh/config)

```
Host spinnaker-start
  HostName <Full DNS>
  ControlMaster yes
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/spinnaker-tunnel.ctl
  RequestTTY no
  LocalForward 9000 127.0.0.1:9000
  LocalForward 8084 127.0.0.1:8084
  LocalForward 8087 127.0.0.1:8087
  User <User name for your vm>

Host spinnaker-stop
  HostName <Full DNS>
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/spinnaker-tunnel.ctl
  RequestTTY no
```

• Create a spinnaker-tunnel.sh file with the following content, and give it execute permissions (chmod 700)

```
#!/bin/bash

socket=$HOME/.ssh/spinnaker-tunnel.ctl

if [ "$1" == "start" ]; then
  if [ ! \( -e ${socket} \) ]; then
    echo "Starting tunnel to Spinnaker..."
    ssh -f -N spinnaker-start && echo "Done."
  else
    echo "Tunnel to Spinnaker running."
  fi
fi

if [ "$1" == "stop" ]; then
  if [ \( -e ${socket} \) ]; then
    echo "Stopping tunnel to Spinnaker..."
    ssh -O "exit" spinnaker-stop && echo "Done."
  else
    echo "Tunnel to Spinnaker stopped."
  fi
fi
```

*Usage*:  To start/stop a SSH tunnel execute the following commands

```
./spinnaker-tunnel.sh start

./spinnaker-tunnel.sh stop
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Larry.  Finally I was able to connect to the Azure VM with Spinnaker.

Comment: When I am trying to create the example "Bake & Deploy test" pipeline, in the Bake stage, the pipeline is stuck with a spinning wheel.  I tried restarting the spinnaker service along with front50 and echo but still the same.  Can you please advise.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You need to configure the Rosco service:

```azure: 
  enabled: true 
  accounts: 
    - name: {same as clouddriver} 
      clientId: {same as clouddriver} 
      appKey: {same as clouddriver} 
      tenantId: {same as clouddriver} 
      subscriptionId: {same as clouddriver} 
      packerResourceGroup: {a pre-created resource group within the above subscription} 
      storageAccount: {a pre-created storage account in the above resource group} ```
 
Note that the resource group and storage account setting allow for only a single location for images.

Comment: If you post a separate question about configuring the bake stage I will post the answer in slightly more detail.