# Spinnaker setup failing on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, spinnaker

I am setting up spinnaker on aws for the first time but couldn't get it working:
I have referred to the existing thread [Spinnaker: not able to access with localhost:9000 on Azure WM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096245/spinnaker-not-able-to-access-with-localhost9000-on-azure-wm) and https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/spinnaker/latest/doc/spinnaker-on-the-aws-cloud.pdf but still couldnt make it working.

I launched ubuntu spinnaker instance with all the settings addressed in the documents and then I then tried to run the spinnnaker page from my local (Windows). Seems like I cant directly connect to spinnaker in my windows browser, (didn't know when I started the setup). 
So, I launched amazon linux instance which would serve as a bastion host. I created a SSH Config file and Spinnaker tunnel sh as given on one of the threads for SSH tunneling. I am using Public key authentication (no passphrase) for login on both the spinnaker and bastion host.

when I tried to start the SSH tunnel from bastion host it failed with error:
Enter passphrase for key '/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys':
Permission denied (publickey).

Not sure why its asking for passphrase when I dont have any associated with the key I am using. 
I am stuck on this and cant proceed. Please help.
Adding to this, I am still wondering if I will be able to get the spinnaker page over bastionhostIP:9000 from my windows browser.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i hope it worked for you. If you need to set up a working spinnaker installation in a compute instance please follow this steps:

1. set up a compute instance with 8 cores cpu and 24GB Memory
2. Access instance and clone project Minnaker [Minnaker Project](https://github.com/armory/minnaker)
3. Execute `all.sh` script and wait about 8 minutes
4. Access Spinnaker in your instance

**Extra steps** (optional) 
 5. Set up spinnaker with an external IP

6. configure a cloud provider (please refer to spinnaker documentation. I suggest armory [armory docs](https://www.armory.io/)
7. Enable providers: Docker, ECR, GitHub, etc.

Enjoy Spinnaker!